# RecyclerView and gridView

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview, android-recyclerview

I implemented gridview using recyclerview the problem is that images are not showing properly like there is so much space between images, here is xml of mainactivity and griditem.xml

mainactivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

griditem.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/iv"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in mainactivity:

```
GridLayoutManager grid = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
recyclerView.setAdapter(new MovieRecyclerAdapter());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(grid);
```

and the result is like this [image]

you can see there is space around two columns of image, how can i remove these spaces?

After height to wrap content [image]

Comment: I did nothing happened

Comment: both height and width of image view and layout to match parent?

Comment: Try recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); before setting adapter.

Comment: Nothing happend

Comment: Post it as an answer if it worked please

Comment: It didn't solve yet @KavachChandra

Comment: Please post your adapter class as well.

Comment: First of all, I would try to use dummy colored rectangles, instead of images, to make sure ImageView.scaleType and wrap_content isn't to blame. Show me what you get

Comment: dummy color images?

Comment: could you answer what you said

Comment: Its only happening with the micky image, but in preview there is no such problem, like huge space around image, when its on gridview, micky image behaviour changes

Comment: Also there are 678 images in gridview, when first time launches it appear with very little delay, but scrolls smoothly, is it normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

**girditem.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

To add spaces between items set the margin to your desired number of dp

Comment: I did like both images are glued and space between them vanished, but vertically there is huge space between each row

Comment: No just accessing and setting data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151325/discussion-between-blackhawk-and-vanna).

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Your item xml outer layout should also have the height as `wrap_content`