# Calling interface method of class

Tags: java, android, oop, interface

I was reading how volley callbacks are implemented [here](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/Response.java)

and how we use it in our code is like this

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonrequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {}
```

so how does Response class able to access its interface methods like this? new Response.Listener is not should be like this?

```
new Response().Listener();
```

accessing with object of response class?

where does this syntax came from, whats the logic?

```
new Response.Listener();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not instantiating Response, you're instantiating Listener (anonymously), which is an inner class(interface) of Response.

this

```
new Response().Listener();
```

is an instance method call, like `new Integer(42).equals(42) or new Thread(..).start()`

this

```
new Response.Listener()
```

is an anonymous inner class instantiation, like `new View.OnClickListener(){..}`, same as a static field/method access: `Boolean.TRUE, Integer.compare(1,2)` (you can see Response as a path to access the Listener class - if it makes it easier for you)

Comment: Listener is inteface which can't be instantiated

Comment: @blackHawk anonymously

Comment: so the code I posted in question is the method to access inner class anonymously or access anunymous inner class?

Comment: @blackHawk you can't access anonymous inner classes, that's why they're anonymous. Response.Listener is the way to access an inner class. new Response.Listener(){...} is an anonymous implementation of the inner class

Comment: Thank you :) could you see my other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555970/recyclerview-and-gridview/45556031?noredirect=1#comment78077198_45556031

Answer (score 1):

I will start from your last question:

> where does this syntax came from, whats the logic? new
>   Response.Listener();

this syntax means, there is a class `Response` that has an interface or class `Listener` defined in it (nested), in your case it's an **interface** , if you had a chance to look at source code of `Response` you may see something like this:

```
public class Response{
    :
    :
    :

    public interface Listener {
        :
        :
        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject);
    }//Listener interface
}//Response class
```

> is not should be like this? new Response().Listener();

No, your suggested code means, create a new instance from `Response` then call a method called `Listener()` from that object (Response)

while this `new Response.Listener` means create new instance of `Listener` which is defined inside `Response`

**Bonus**: now as `Listener`is an interface, you can't create instance of it.
so what should be done is:

1- Create new class that `implements Listener` and overrides `onResponse()` and pass it as param to `JsonObjectRequest(...)`

ex,

```
public class MyListern implements Response.Listener{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        //put your implementation here ...
    } 
}//Response class

MyListern mMyListern = new MyListern();
JsonObjectRequest jsonrequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, mMyListern);
```

OR

2- create an *anonymous inner class*, and pass it as a param to `JsonObjectRequest(...)` (it's the way you posted in the question)

**--EDIT: extra Bonus :)**
mMyListern is instance of the class MyListern, that implements Listener which is defined in `Response` so it's not Response class, it's MyListener.

you can think of `Response.Listener` as a path, if you say

`c:\users\john\Desktop`

this is a path points to Desktop, that exists inside `john`, and john exists in `users`, so **Desktop** is NOT **users**

Comment: Thank you, yeah anonymously, I dont understand this: MyListern mMyListern = new MyListern();
JsonObjectRequest jsonrequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, mMyListern);        is it Response class?

Comment: @blackHawk , no it's `MyListener` check my updated answer

Comment: @blackHawk you can think of Response.Listener as a path, if you say
`c:\users\john\Desktop`
this is a path points to Desktop, that exists inside john, and john exists in users, so Desktop is NOT users

Comment: Thank you, could you see my other question ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555970/recyclerview-and-gridview/45556031?noredirect=1#comment78077198_45556031

Answer (score 1):

It is just a nested class(1). For instance:

```
public class A {
  ...
  public static class B { ... }
}
```

Class A is just like a package for class B, so to create a new instance you need to write

```
new A.B();
```

But actually that code is instantiating an anonymous class that extends the inner class:

```
B myB = new A.B() {
  //methods overriden here
};
```

(1) B can also be an interface. In that case you cannot instantiate it so the only option is creating an anonymous class. I've not read the current implementation of that Response class, so I don't know if Listener is a class or an interface

Comment: Listener is an interface, also we can't instantiate interface

Comment: Thank you :) could you see my other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555970/recyclerview-and-gridview/45556031?noredirect=1#comment78077198_45556031